# How to avoid dependency cycles with shared packages?

Tags: go, design-patterns, circular-dependency

I know this gets asked a lot but I still don't understand how to fix it. Say I have this structure:

```
foo
- foos.go      // custom foo type
database
- database.go  // interface
- postgres.go  // implementation
```

In `database.go` I need to import `foo`, so I can `saveOnDb(foo.myfoo)`, and in `foos.go` I need to import `database`, so I can `database.saveOnDb(myfoo)`.

This doesn't compile because of the import cycle. What would the correct design be?

Comment: Put your types in a separate, shared package, with no dependencies.

Comment: Why do they need to be separate packages, or why are you trying to do the same thing in 2 different packages?

Comment: @JimB I have many packages and they all need to save stuff on the db. Are you saying it would be better to break the `database` interface into every single package that only saves its own things instead of having just one, centralized database package?

Comment: @Flimzy thank you, that makes sense. Reading your other comment I wonder why coupling different packages to a shared type package is better than spreading the db code across packages?

Comment: Why is `foo` calling `database.saveOnDb`? Usually you'd have something depending on both packages so that it can use the `foo` type and save it to the database. But it's hard to offer much advice with so little information.

Comment: @Adrian `foo` is calling `database.saveOnDb` to save itself, and `database` is an interface so I can mock it for tests. I don't understand what you meant in the rest of your comment though

Answer (score 1):

Database should not depend on foo, it should be abstract enough.

Rather than `saveOnDb(foo.myfoo)` could you use an interface?

```
type somefoo interface{}

saveOnDb(somefoo)
```

then call it

```
database.saveOnDb(myfoo)
```

Answer (score -3):

Another way to approach this is to put foo in charge of saving to the database instead, so foo calls the db package, and other packages just call foo.Save and don't care about the db package. So instead of:

```
database.saveOnDb(myfoo)
```

If you want to save fields of a foo have this method on an instance of foo which uses the database package to save internally:

```
foo.Save()
```

And also in foos (or foo) package you'll probably want

```
foos.Create()
foos.Find()
foos.FindAll()
```

Which know all about foos and how to return them - the db package should not know that, so it should not import foo.

Your database package definitely shouldn't know about specific types, it should know about talking to the database. Also have a look at some orms if you prefer a more generic solution (but this will require using interface{} a lot).

Comment: This is a step in the wrong direction. It means spreading your db code across packages. This is not good design.

Comment: The db code is in the db package. Code about your types, including instantiating them, should go with the types (wherever they live) IMO. How you structure your packages is a function of taste and the problem domain, there isn't one true way to structure go packages.

Comment: There's no "one true way", but there are obvious design smells. And spreading database code across packages is one of the smelliest, and most obvious violations of SOLID principles. Of course, if you don't care about or desire clean code, then do whatever you want.

Comment: How do you propose that `foo` know how to write to the database, then?

Comment: So then your `foo.Create()` et al, are just wrappers for `db.XXX`, so you haven't solved anything. You've only added redirection.